# Event when a sections' entry type changes layout?

Tags: entry-type, events

Is there a way or an event available to detect changes on the fieldlayout of an entrytype? We've wrote a piece of middleware that needs to be informed of such changes.

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now, and technically Craft actually deletes the old Field Layout and creates a new one each time you save an Entry Type, since it would be more trouble than it’s worth to keep the old one and compare it to the new POST data for changes.

So, we could add a new `onSaveEntryType` event to SectionsService, which would end up getting called whenever the Field Layout changes. I’ll add that to the 2.3 list.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Also for our planning, is there an ETA on 2.3? Thanks

Comment: @pythic Sometime before the end of the year.